# PerformancePoint unable to retrieve KPI definition from cube

Tags: performancepoint

While running PPS 2010 Dashboard designer I am getting the following error while trying to import any KPI out a cube. I am using the Adventure Work DW 2008 R2. I can see the KPI while in BIDS and even browse them, but stll unable to imported. In the meantime , I am manually getting the measure out of the cube and creating the KPI.

Exception details:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Server.ImportExportHelper.GetImportableAsKpis(DataSource asDataSource)
at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.Server.PmServer.GetImportableAsKpis(DataSource dataSource)

I am running SharePoint 2010 64 bit
 and SQL 2008 R2 64 bit in another server

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution provided by josh  at Microsoft also

Can you try to download the latest Analysis Services Management Objects and install it on the SharePoint server?  The latest link I have is -

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=CEB4346F-657F-4D28-83F5-AAE0C5C83D52&displaylang=en#amo

Which is the SQL Server 2008 R2 feature pack.  Olaptalk would know if you can find it on the file system of your R2 server.

PS. make sure that you re-start the server after the install.

Thank you
Tomas 
Microsoft